# Андроид. Эта непонятная кнопка "домой"

Tags: android-sdk, android, события, activity

Есть приложение. По выходу из него, запускается сервис, который через время автоматически его (приложение, активити) запускает. И когда нажимается кнопка назад, всё работает хорошо. Но вот когда кнопка домой, активити не удаляется же. И тут проблема, мало того что со временем вызова что-то (тут попробую сам разобраться), так оно зачем то создаёт ещё одну дублирующую активити (только уже пустую). Это всё происходит в главной активити.

В общем уже голову сломал, что тут делать. Первое что на ум приходит - это просто удалять активити (аналогично кнопке "назад") по нажатию кнопки "домой". Но вот ничего не вышло через простую обработку кейэфентов (на стековерфлов пишут что это вообще невозможно). А другой выход... Я вообще не понимаю почему такое происходит. Если сервис не запускать, то дублирующая активити не создаётся, всё нормально.

**Добавлено**
Код вызова активити из сервиса:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Постойте, но, насколько я понял, вы ведь сами создаёте из сервиса ещё один экземпляр этой же `activity`? Так чему же вы удивляетесь тогда?

Comment: По идее оно не должно так делать. Должно ведь вызываться уже созданное активити... Добавил код вызова активити из сервиса, хотя сомневаюсь что проблема только там.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть ощущение, что неправильно используется [Tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). Также есть ощущение что если запускать их с флагом `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_STACK` (название пишу на память) добавив в манифест атрибут активити: `android:launchMode="singleTask"` то все будет хорошо.

Comment: Ваш совет помог ) Причём даже не нужно устанавливать флаг, достаточно просто в манифесте singleTask прописать. 
Одно только непонятно. Активити запускается слишком долго. Если я нажму кнопку назад, то сервис запустит его мгновенно, а если через кнопку домой то запускаться будет секунды 4. Причём это происходит даже если убрать Thread.sleep, то есть время передаётся верно...

Comment: Нужно дебажить и смотреть код. Все что угодно может быть. Рад что помог :)